# Null exception at powershell script AD users

Tags: powershell

This is the script

```
$aryUser= import-csv -Path E:\shares\DATA\Userstest.csv
$Class = "User"
$dc = "dc=gc,dc=dean,dc=local"
$null | skip-null 
foreach($strUser in $aryUser)
{
 $ou ="ou="+ $strUser.OU
 $ADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://$ou,$dc" 
 $cnuser="cn="+ $($strUser.userName)
 $User = $ADSI.Create($Class,$cnuser)
 $User.put("SamaccountName", $($strUser.SamAccountName))
 $User.setInfo()
 $User.put("userPassword", $($strUser.Password))
 $user.psbase.invokeset("AccountDisabled", "False")
 $User.setInfo()
 $User.put("GivenName", $($strUser.GivenName))
 $User.put("sn", $($strUser.sn))
 $User.put("DisplayName", $($strUser.DisplayName))
 $User.put("description", $($strUser.description))
 $User.put("physicalDeliveryOfficeName", $($strUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName))
 $User.put("telephoneNumber", $($strUser.telephoneNumber))
 $User.put("mail", $($strUser.mail))
 $User.put("wwwHomePage", $($strUser.wwwHomePage))
 $User.put("streetAddress", $($strUser.streetAddress))
 $User.put("postOfficeBox", $($strUser.postOfficeBox))
 $User.put("l", $($strUser.l))
 $User.put("st", $($strUser.st))
 $User.put("postalCode", $($strUser.postalCode))
 $User.put("c", $($strUser.c))
 $User.put("ipPhone", $($strUser.ipPhone))
 $User.put("Department", $($strUser.Department))
 $User.put("Company", $($strUser.Company))
 $User.setInfo()
}
```

I'm constantly get this error

> n
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   E:\Shares\DATA\bier.ps1:11 char:32
>   +  $User.put("SamaccountName", $($strUser.SamAccountName))
>   +                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeExceptio
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   E:\Shares\DATA\bier.ps1:12 char:2
>   +  $User.setInfo()
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeExceptio
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   E:\Shares\DATA\bier.ps1:13 char:30
>   +  $User.put("userPassword", $($strUser.Password))
>   +                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeExceptio
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   E:\Shares\DATA\bier.ps1:14 char:2
>   +  $user.psbase.invokeset("AccountDisabled", "False")
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeExceptio
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Looks like your `$user` object is null. Therefore you cannot call a method on it as mentioned by the message.

Comment: so how would i fix it

Comment: I would start by checking this line `$User = $ADSI.Create($Class,$cnuser)`. Check the parameters for their validity, like the OU exists, etc. There was no error returned from that line? Put a break after and check the value of $user.

Comment: Something that looks weird is `dc=gc` as part of `$dc`. You have a domain named gc?

Comment: yes, full domain = gc.dean.local